# Why are CancellationTokens not working if local methods are used?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

Given the following code you would expect that the DoWait method is executed for one second in both cases. However, it works for the first case but hangs for the second.

If we add async/await to the local method the behavior is as expected.

Given that that CTs are structs and hence passed around by value, not reference, can anyone explain explain what's going on?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //not using local method
            using var cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Console.WriteLine(await DoWait(cts1.Token));

            //using a local method
            Task<long> LocalMethod()
            {
                using var cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                return DoWait(cts1.Token);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(await LocalMethod());
        }

        static async Task<long> DoWait(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var elapsedMilliseconds = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    elapsedMilliseconds = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            return elapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `CancellationTokenSource` is disposed before the asynchronous part of the method starts. Such are the perils of invoking asynchronous code without `async`/`await`; this is safe only if you are doing a trivial pass-through, which is not the case here.

Comment: Take a look at [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) by Stephen Cleary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CancellationTokenSource` you're creating within `LocalMehtod` is being disposed when that method returns.  Since it's disposed, it can no longer cancel the token you already passed to `DoWait`.

In the version where you make the local method async/await, it doesn't get disposed, so can carry on working as expected.

Comment: Blimey, you're right! Removing the using statement makes it work as advertised. 

Actually it's not the token being disposed (since it's been passed by value) but it's its CancellationTokenSource. Just wish it was more obvious.

Comment: Don't fix it by removing the `using` statement though - that (probably) just makes it an even more indeterminate error, because you can't now predict when the garbage collector will dispose the CTS for you, so it might work sometimes and not others.

Comment: Of course not. I've fixed by adding async/await but was unable to understand what was going on.